# Android: Is WebView affected by Java heap limit?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, heap-memory

I read that Android Java applications have a limitation for heap memory. I would like to know if WebView content is allocated on that heap or it uses C allocation.

Comment: issue/webview bug in webkit http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my observations of viewing my Android app memory using DDMS/MAT, the WebView has a minimal footprint in the heap and any memory used by applications within the WebView are allocated directly from system memory, avoiding the heap.

My application is quite large, 30+ MB on lauch, and the WebView still only reports a minimal size on the heap, I think it was between 300K-400K.

Use Dalvik Debug Monitor (DDMS) to capture a memory dump. 
Use Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) to analyze the dump.

Watch this video for a tutorial on how to use these tools to examine your Android memory usage and prove to yourself this is true:

http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/

Answer (score 0):

As you said android java applications have a limitation for heap memory.It is based on Device.
for

```
G1 Device--heap size is ---16MB
Droid --------------------24MB
Nexus one-----------------36MB
XOOM-----------------------48MB
```

You can go through following video .. it has described very well

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: I think he's asking if a WebView, probably because of underlying WebKit, adds to the Java heap, or uses native allocation.